# How to get the table row td's value that has a row span column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with rowspan as a starting column. The table has a button at the end of each row. When the button is clicked, the corresponding rows values should be retrieved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <table border="1" style="text-align:center" >
    <tr>
      <th> Col 1 </th>
      <th> Col 2 </th>
      <th> Col 3 </th>
      <th> Get Row Values </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="col1"> 1 </td>
      <td class="col2"> 2 </td>
      <td class="col3"> 3 </td>
      <td> <button class="get-value"> Alert values </button> </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col2"> 5 </td>
      <td class="col3"> 6 </td>
      <td> <button class="get-value"> Alert values </button> </td>
   </tr>    
  </table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('.get-value').on("click",function(){
       var col1val = $(this).parents('tr').find('.col1').text();
       var col2val = $(this).parents('tr').find('.col2').text();
       var col3val = $(this).parents('tr').find('.col3').text();
       alert("Col1 :" + col1val + " Col2 :" + col2val + " Col3 :"+ col3val);
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the first row button is clicked, it is retrieving all the three columns values. But when the second row button is clicked, the rowspan column value could not be retrieved.

Comment: What result are you expecting, because it seems to work just fine

Comment: That's because the second button does not have the same parent row as the first button.  An easier way to do this would be to assign the big `td` (Col 1) an ID, then target it that way from both buttons.

Comment: @Carsten & Craig It doesn't work fine ...

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I thought so too, but if you look at the alert generated by the second button, it doesn't show a value for Col1.

Comment: I see, sorry i missed that  `1`

Comment: The parent element of the cell with row-span is the first row, not the second-one. `parents` matches "_elements ordered from immediate parent on up_", the first row is a sibling of the second row, hence not found by the method.

Comment: @Teemu is there any way i cen get it

Comment: That depends on the real array structure you have. Maybe find the closest span attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a `row1, row2` e.t.c. class for each "row". Then it's easy to get the value of the `rowspan` cells with a `$('.row'+index+'.col1')` selector. Check this:

```js
  $('.get-value').on("click",function(){
       var index = $('.get-value').index($(this))+1;//+1 because index is zero-based
       var col1val = $('.row'+index+ '.col1').text();
       var col2val = $('.row'+index+ '.col2').text();
       var col3val = $('.row'+index+ '.col3').text();
       alert("Col1 :" + col1val + " Col2 :" + col2val + " Col3 :"+ col3val);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="text-align:center" >
    <tr>
      <th> Col 1 </th>
      <th> Col 2 </th>
      <th> Col 3 </th>
      <th> Get Row Values </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="col1 row1 row2"> 1 </td>
      <td class="col2 row1"> 2 </td>
      <td class="col3 row1"> 3 </td>
      <td> <button class="get-value"> Alert values </button> </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col2 row2"> 5 </td>
      <td class="col3 row2"> 6 </td>
      <td> <button class="get-value"> Alert values </button> </td>
   </tr>    
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the first line of the Function to

```
var col1val = $(this).parents('table').find('.col1').text();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <table border="1" style="text-align:center" >
    <tr>
      <th> Col 1 </th>
      <th> Col 2 </th>
      <th> Col 3 </th>
      <th> Get Row Values </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" class="col1"> 1 </td>
      <td class="col2"> 2 </td>
      <td class="col3"> 3 </td>
      <td> <button class="get-value"> Alert values </button> </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col2"> 5 </td>
      <td class="col3"> 6 </td>
      <td> <button class="get-value"> Alert values </button> </td>
   </tr>    
  </table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $('.get-value').on("click",function(){
       var col1val = $(this).parents('table').find('.col1').text();
       var col2val = $(this).parents('tr').find('.col2').text();
       var col3val = $(this).parents('tr').find('.col3').text();
       alert("Col1 :" + col1val + " Col2 :" + col2val + " Col3 :"+ col3val);
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ,this is just a example i have mentioned ,but in my application ,the table is large with lot of rows span columns,in that case above mentioned solution wont work