# get value in td with rowspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with rowspan as a starting column. The table has a button at the end of each row. When the button is clicked, the corresponding rows values should be retrieved.

```js
$('.get-value').on("click",function(){
   var col1val = $(this).parents('table').find('.col1').text();
   var col2val = $(this).parents('tr').find('.col2').text();
   var col3val = $(this).parents('tr').find('.col3').text();
   var col4val = $(this).parents('tr').find('.col4').text();
   alert("Col1 :" + col1val + " Col2 :" + col2val + " Col3 :"+ col3val + " Col4 :" + col4val);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="text-align:center" >
  <tr>
    <th> Col 1 </th>
    <th> Col 2 </th>
    <th> Col 3 </th>
    <th> Col 4 </th>
    <th> Get Row Values </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5" class="col1"> 1 </td>
    <td class="col2"> 2 </td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="col3"> 4 </td>
    <td class="col4"> 5 </td>
    <td  rowspan="2" > <button class="get-value"> Alert 1 </button> </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col2"> 3 </td>
    <td class="col3"> 6 </td>
  <tr>
    <td class="col2"> 10 </td>
    <td rowspan="3" class="col3"> 13 </td>
    <td class="col4"> 14 </td>
  <tr>
    <td class="col2"> 11 </td>
    <td class="col3"> 15 </td>
 </tr>    
  <tr>
    <td class="col2"> 12 </td>
    <td class="col3"> 16 </td>
    <td rowspan="2" > <button class="get-value"> Alert 2 </button> </td>
 </tr>    
</table>
```

when alert 1 or alert 2 clicked , not all value be retrieved

> alert 1   i want result 1,2,3,4,5,6
>
> alert 2   i want result 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16

learn from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626451/how-to-get-the-table-row-tds-value-that-has-a-row-span-column) , but not same

help

Comment: hint: you have multiple td for a row... what about having a look at [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the data being presented really tabular in nature?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. First you need rows, but you are computing columns. Then you get only parent tr when you should get table.

Here it is, I refactored it for you. Fell free to ask if you don't understand something.

```js
function parseAndRemoveDuplicates(arr) {
    arr = arr.split(" ").filter(e=>e)
    arr = arr.filter((v,i) => arr.indexOf(v) == i).join(" ");
    return arr;
}

$('.get-value').on("click",function(){
       var row1val = $(this).parents('table').find('.row1').text();
       var row2val = $(this).parents('table').find('.row2').text();
       var row3val = $(this).parents('table').find('.row3').text();
       var row4val = $(this).parents('table').find('.row4').text();
       var row5val = $(this).parents('table').find('.row5').text();
       var rowsValues = "Row1 :" + row1val + " Row2 :" + row2val + " Row3 :"+ row3val + " Row4 :" + row4val + " Row5 :" + row4val;
       var alert1 = parseAndRemoveDuplicates(row1val + row2val);
       var alert2 = parseAndRemoveDuplicates(row3val + row4val + row5val);
       console.log(alert1);
       console.log(alert2);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="text-align:center" >
    <tr>
      <th> Col 1 </th>
      <th> Col 2 </th>
      <th> Col 3 </th>
      <th> Col 4 </th>
      <th> Get Row Values </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5" class="row1 row2 row3 row4 row5"> 1 </td>
      <td class="row1"> 2 </td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="row1 row2"> 4 </td>
      <td class="row1"> 5 </td>
      <td  rowspan="2" > <button class="get-value"> Alert 1 </button> </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row2"> 3 </td>
      <td class="row2"> 6 </td>
    <tr>
      <td class="row3"> 10 </td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="row3 row4 row5"> 13 </td>
      <td class="row3"> 14 </td>
    <tr>
      <td class="row4"> 11 </td>
      <td class="row4"> 15 </td>
   </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td class="row5"> 12 </td>
      <td class="row5"> 16 </td>
      <td rowspan="2" > <button class="get-value"> Alert 2 </button> </td>
   </tr>    
  </table>
```

here is a better version:

```js
function parseAndRemoveDuplicates(arr) {
    arr = arr.split(" ").filter(e=>e)
    arr = arr.filter((v,i) => arr.indexOf(v) == i).join(" ");
    return arr;
}

function getValuesFromRows(obj, rowclasses) {
       var table = $(obj).parents('table');
       return parseAndRemoveDuplicates(table.find(rowclasses).text());
}

$('.get-value').on("click",function(){
       var alert1 = getValuesFromRows(this, '.row1,.row2');
       var alert2 = getValuesFromRows(this, '.row3,.row4,.row5');
       console.log(alert1);
       console.log(alert2);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="text-align:center" >
    <tr>
      <th> Col 1 </th>
      <th> Col 2 </th>
      <th> Col 3 </th>
      <th> Col 4 </th>
      <th> Get Row Values </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="5" class="row1 row2 row3 row4 row5"> 1 </td>
      <td class="row1"> 2 </td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="row1 row2"> 4 </td>
      <td class="row1"> 5 </td>
      <td  rowspan="2" > <button class="get-value"> Alert 1 </button> </td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row2"> 3 </td>
      <td class="row2"> 6 </td>
    <tr>
      <td class="row3"> 10 </td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="row3 row4 row5"> 13 </td>
      <td class="row3"> 14 </td>
    <tr>
      <td class="row4"> 11 </td>
      <td class="row4"> 15 </td>
   </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td class="row5"> 12 </td>
      <td class="row5"> 16 </td>
      <td rowspan="2" > <button class="get-value"> Alert 2 </button> </td>
   </tr>    
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you to all of you , all code working .   can't accept answer ,

Answer (score 0):

The following code, amends the first answer of Nelson Teixeira by having each alert provide the numerical values in a sorted order.  Also, when you click each alert, now the code provides only the data corresponding to the specific alert, as follows:

```js
function parseAndRemoveDuplicates(arr) {
  arr = arr.split(" ").filter(e => e)
  arr = arr.filter((v, i) => arr.indexOf(v) == i).sort().join(" ");
  return arr;
}

function getValuesFromRows(obj, rowclasses) {
  var table = $(obj).parents('table');
  return parseAndRemoveDuplicates(table.find(rowclasses).text());
}
$('#but1').on("click", function() {
  var alert1 = getValuesFromRows(this, '.row1,.row2');
  console.log(alert1);
});
$('#but2').on("click", function() {
  var alert2 = getValuesFromRows(this, '.row3,.row4,.row5');

  console.log(alert2);



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" style="text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <th> Col 1 </th>
    <th> Col 2 </th>
    <th> Col 3 </th>
    <th> Col 4 </th>
    <th> Get Row Values </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5" class="row1 row2 row3 row4 row5"> 1 </td>
    <td class="row1"> 2 </td>
    <td rowspan="2" class="row1 row2"> 4 </td>
    <td class="row1"> 5 </td>
    <td rowspan="2"> <button id='but1' class="get-value"> Alert 1 </button> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row2"> 3 </td>
    <td class="row2"> 6 </td>
    <tr>
      <td class="row3"> 10 </td>
      <td rowspan="3" class="row3 row4 row5"> 13 </td>
      <td class="row3"> 14 </td>
      <tr>
        <td class="row4"> 11 </td>
        <td class="row4"> 15 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="row5"> 12 </td>
        <td class="row5"> 16 </td>
        <td rowspan="2"> <button id='but2' class="get-value"> Alert 2 </button> </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

In order to sort the numerical values, the code slightly tweaks `parseAndRemoveDuplicates()` by sorting the array values before joining them into a string result.

Admittedly, the solution for having each alert provide distinct data, involves less than elegant code, adding a unique id to each button element and then creating a similar function for each to display the corresponding result.